# How to fix CSRF token error in sentry in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, sentry

I use Sentry to log errors in asp.net core 7, but errors not show in Sentry and I have this error in console log: `CSRF Verification Failed A required security token was not found or was invalid`. This is my code in program.cs:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
         .UseSentry(o =>
                        {
                            o.Dsn = @"http://876a08b927d4efcb98a769314452bbe@192.168.34.80:9000/8";
                            o.Debug = true;
                        })
        .Build();
```

I test my code in .net 5 project and I can see logs in sentry panel.

Comment: If you chamge the same app from net7.0 to net5.0 it works? Or you já é a different app/set up than happens to be net5 that works?

Comment: if you call SentrySdk.CaptureMessage("test") from an action or elsewhere does it work?

Comment: No I have another .net 5 project and can log errors with same config in same project

Comment: I suggest creating an issue on GitHub and sharing a repro so folks can take a look: http://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/ Logs (since u put Debug=true) can also be helpful

Comment: @BrunoGarcia  I found that my .net 5 sentry package version is  2.1.8 and .net 7 project is 3.26.1. I downgrade  .net 7 sentry package version to 21.8 and it  worked

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- You said version 2.1.8 of the Sentry .NET SDK works.  However, I don't recommend using that, as it's quite old (released Nov 21, 2020).  We have fixed many issues and added many features since then.
  You should read through the [2.x to 3.x migration guide](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/migration/).
- From the DSN, it appears you are self-hosting the Sentry server.  Versions 3.x of the Sentry .NET SDK requires Sentry version 20.6.0 or greater to work correctly.  [See docs here](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/migration/#self-hosted-support).  The reason is that we now use Sentry's [envelope endpoint](https://develop.sentry.dev/sdk/envelopes/).  I suspect you are using an older version of Sentry.

  - Additionally, if using Sentry .NET 3.17.0 or greater, you'll either need Sentry 21.9.0 or greater, or will need to set `options.SendClientReports = false`.  (See [changelog notes](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#3170).)
- The CSRF failure has been [discussed before](https://forum.sentry.io/t/csrf-verification-failed-token-was-not-found-or-was-invalid/12177) with regard to using newer Sentry SDKs with older self-hosted Sentry servers.
- You may also find that you need to update the configuration or architecture of your self-hosted Sentry server.  See [the documentation](https://develop.sentry.dev/self-hosted/).
- There have been other issues on this subject with Sentry self-hosted in the past.  You may want to [review them](https://github.com/getsentry/self-hosted/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20%22CSRF%20Verification%22), or [raise a new issue](https://develop.sentry.dev/self-hosted/support/) if necessary.